# KineticJS - on click event

Tags: html5-animation, kineticjs

I am working on a small application working with KineticJS. I have a circle created and am fading it in upon page load... the problem I am running into is that when I click the main circle to "spawn" smaller circles around the main one, all of the circles disappear...

http://jsfiddle.net/T9RfA/1/

Anyone else run into this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! It ended up being an issue with the way I was setting the opacity for the Layer that was holding the circles.

Updated Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/T9RfA/2/